# Why is my zfs backup so small?

Tags: zfs

*While asking this question, I have figured it out and will be self-answering*.

I have backed up my data (`tank`) to a file-based zfs pool on an NTFS drive (`indoorpool`). However, it now looks like the backup is taking up a lot less space than the original. Why is this? Was my backup done fully and successfully?

```bash
$ zfs get compression,compressratio,used tank indoorpool
NAME        PROPERTY       VALUE     SOURCE
indoorpool  compression    off       default
indoorpool  compressratio  1.53x     -
indoorpool  used           261G      -
tank        compression    lz4       local
tank        compressratio  1.32x     -
tank        used           457G      -
```

I find it odd that

- Compression is disabled on the backup but enabled on the original
- Despite that, there is a high compressratio
- The backup is taking up 196G less space

### Backup Creation

```
# create file of size 1Terabyte
sudo truncate -s 1T /media/generic/My\ Passport/indoorpool_20230206.zpool

# create zfs pool inside that file
sudo zpool create indoorpool /media/generic/My\ Passport/indoorpool_20230206.zpool 

# send data from my original pool to the backup
# -R means recurse into lower datasets
# -w means to send raw (the original is encrypted)
sudo zfs send -Rw tank/ds1@backup2302062136 | sudo zfs receive -u -d indoorpool
```

I let this run overnight and it did not report any errors.

#### No Snaps are Missing

Comparing the outputs of

```bash
zfs list -t snap -s creation -r tank/ds1
zfs list -t snap -s creation -r indoorpool/ds1
```

does not show a difference. Same number of lines. ( 5996, because docker likes to create zfs datasets >.< )

Answer (score 0):

I missed that I had some datasets outside `tank/ds1`.

### How to List all Datasets

```bash
zfs list -r tank
```

Use sed to get rid of the clutter that the docker datasets add in the list command's output:

```bash
zfs list | sed -E '\#/u18/.{12}#,+1d#'
```

This gives a good overview over *all* datasets and their mountpoints, that I had manually created but deletes every occurrence of `/u18/asdfasdfasdfasdf` and the following line, because that is where my six thousand autogenerated datasets reside.

### My Solution

I had a dataset `tank/nosnap` of size 186G and a `tank/var` dataset of a few kilobytes that I completely forgot about.

Removing 186G from the original size of the `zpool list` output

```
zpool list
NAME         SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
indoorpool  1016G   261G   755G        -         -     0%    25%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
tank         572G   457G   115G        -         -    54%    79%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

leaves me with 271G, which *does* correspond to the `USED` value of the backup (`indoorpool`).

The only thing that I still don't get is why there is a `compressratio` when the `compression` is reported as off (or why it is disabled at all).